# Having problems detecting both LMB and RMB at the same time. Is my mouse broken?

Tags: mouse, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a game in Unity3D. One of the features in the game involves having both LMB and RMB pressed at the same time.

My problem is that I tested my code with my own mouse a Trust/15315 and it was not able to register both buttons pressed at the same time, but just the 2 of them individually. I then tested the same code with 3 other mouses and it worked perfectly.

My questions are: Is my mouse not working properly by being broken? Or is this a feature in my mouse? Are there other mouses that are built to act like this (not being able to detect both mouse buttons down at the same time)?

As asked I added the code used:

```java
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gestures : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {

        print (Input.GetMouseButton(0)+" "+Input.GetMouseButton(2) + " "+ Input.GetMouseButton(1));

    }   
}
```

Also I would like to add that the left and the middle buttons work together but the right doesn't work with the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if it's intended by Unity or not to get a clean single button click implementation across different mice and OSs.

I struggled with a similar problem and found out that it's more reliable to read the mouse button status from [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) and [Input.GetMouseButtonUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) events.

Answer (score 1):

> I then tested the same code with 3 other mouses and it worked perfectly.

It sounds like it is just your mouse. Tracking down the exact issue is tricky since there are so many steps in the process. (hardware -> onboard software -> wireless -> drivers -> OS -> Unity) Sloppy implementation at any point in that process could theoretically cause an issue like you described.

As others have mentioned, the mouse events can be a bit glitchy even in the best of times. The good news is that, depending on what exactly you need to do, there is usually a work around.

If you are aiming to handle single vs. double click this might be useful: [simultaneous single and double click functions](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19747/simultaneous-single-and-double-click-functions.html)

If you are looking for click-and-hold sort of behavior you will likely want to look at mapping the mouse buttons via [Input.GetAxis](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).